# Segmentation fault при отправке POST запроса

Tags: c++, qt, http

Написал простенький класс для отправки post запроса. Проблема в том что на строчке

> reply = manager.post(request, multiPart);

происходит SEG FAULT. Что я делаю не так?

**HTTP_Adapter.h**

```
#ifndef HTTP_ADAPTER_H
#define HTTP_ADAPTER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QHttpMultiPart>
#include <QDebug>

class HTTP_Adapter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    QUrl apiUrl;
    QByteArray requestString;




public:
    explicit HTTP_Adapter(QObject *parent = 0);
    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart;

signals:

public slots:
    void getReplyFinished();
    void readyReadReply();

};

#endif // HTTP_ADAPTER_H
```

**http_adapter.cpp**

```
#include "http_adapter.h"

HTTP_Adapter::HTTP_Adapter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/ping/";
    requestString = "method=getQuote&format=xml";
    QNetworkRequest request(apiUrl);


    multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
    QHttpPart textPart;
    textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"text\""));
    textPart.setBody("my text");
    multiPart->append(textPart);


    //reply = manager.post(request, requestString);
    reply = manager.post(request, multiPart);
    multiPart->setParent(reply);

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),this, SLOT(getReplyFinished()));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyReadReply()));
}

void HTTP_Adapter::getReplyFinished()
{
    reply->deleteLater();
    multiPart->deleteLater();
}

void HTTP_Adapter::readyReadReply()
{
    QString answer = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
    qDebug() << answer << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <http_adapter.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    HTTP_Adapter http;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Ошибок нет. У меня всё работает.